# Theano on Windows 10

Tags: python, g++, theano, keras, theano-cuda

I had Theano (with Keras and nolearn) properly installed and running on my GPU Windows 10 system.

After adding some additional installations (Kaldi/ PDNN), I keep getting these two warnings when importing theano and, as mentioned below, I am having severe degradation in performance.

```
**WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)**
```

I have read some post about g++ installation but I am pretty sure that it is some overridden configuration issue.

Has anyone ran into this problem? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: And you definitely have `g++`?

Comment: it might have been lost while playing around trying to fix it. how can I check it ? whats the simplest installation?

Comment: C:\Users\User>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20111220 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.